# blender crashing on startup

Tags: intel-graphics, gpu-driver

ive been having headaches with this problem. Blender keeps on crashing when i start it up, this problem happened when i installed mesa-utils. This made my games run faster but it blender keeps on crashing now.

is there anyway to downgrade to the graphics driver that came with ubuntu?
My iGPU is an Intel HD 620

My Specs:
Intel Core i3-7020U
4gb ram
32 gb temporary boot drive

Things i have done
Uninstall mesa-utils
Used oibaf's mesa driver
Tried to downgrade to the first version with a nVidia tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems blender isn't compatable with newer version mesa, try `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965 blender`
ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_graphics

Comment: thanks! it worked now